# How to modify a lot of html files at the same time?

Tags: html, css, fedora20

I have thousands of HTML files that I would like to modify at the same time on a Fedora system.
It would be to replace `style.css` by `../headers.css` and to replace another long chain that you can see here : http://pastebin.com/PHAz8Q4C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a tool like `sed` which can do text/regex replacements on a file.

Combining this with `find` and `xargs` is a good start to making it work on a large number of files.

So, for example, you could do something like

`find -name "*.html" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's#style.css#../headers.css#g'`

Since there is no way to undo this operation, I would recommend making a backup of the files just in case (or use version control!)

EDIT:
Guide on how to expand this to other search/replace terms (like your pastebin):

Same idea. Just make sure you escape everything properly. As an explanation that can get you further...

- `find` finds all the `html` files
- `xargs` runs the command after it on each file
- `sed` does the replacement
- `-i` tells `sed` to do it in place
- `s` tells it to `Substitute`
- `style.css` is what to replace
- `../headers.css` is what to replace it with
- and `g` tells it to replace all occurrences in the file.

Comment: Thanks, but what about the code on pastebin ?

Comment: Edited with info on how you can do it. Feel free to follow up if you have problems but that should be enough for you to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

For your long code, you can try this one :

```
find . -name "*.html" -exec sed -i 's#<a href="\.\./index.html">&laquo;</a> <h1>\(.*\)</h1>#<section class="skin-organic" role="region">\n  <header>\n    <a href="../index.html"><span class="icon icon-back">back</span></a>\n    <h1>\1</h1>\n  </header>\n</section>#g' {} \;
```

Comment: I tried your code and it only delete some code and don't display what I want.

Comment: Are you sure your sample are correct? My code replaces `<a href="../index.html">&laquo;</a> <h1><h1 style="color: blue">[Anything]</h1>`

Comment: See https://github.com/mrtino/bible/tree/master/bible to see all the code.